# tfs 2010 does not sense file change that open from outside of project

Tags: tfs

Is it possible that set a configuration that TFS 2010 sense file change from outside of project? Consider I open a *.cs file with note pad and then change it's content and when open the project TFS 2010 mark it as checked out?

thanks

Comment: TFS 11 will be able to with its local workspaces. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As leppie said TFS dont get the changes alone (without VS).

But if you often work without VS you can install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools August 2011](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).

After installing you have some extended entries in the contextmenu of the windows explorer
(on the folders/paths which have a workspace mapping definied).

Looks like

[image]

Comment: I use this all the time. Very handy.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what other folks here have mentioned, you can do

```
tf edit [filename]
```

from a command prompt http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx

Also, in order to change a file you will need to attrib -R to make it writable.  If you do that, you can change as many files as you want and then with one command, pend edits to all writable files using the power tools K.Hoffman mentioned.  To do that, run:

```
tfpt online
```

A good writeup here

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/09/03/using-tfpt-command-line-tool.aspx

> **Online Command** 
>   Use the online command to create pending edits on
>   writable files that do not have pending edits.
>
> Example: tfpt [/deletes] [/adds] [/diff] [/noprompt [/preview]
>   [/purge]] [/exclude:filespec1,filespec2,...] [filespec...]
>   [/recursive]

Answer (score 2):

If you checkout the file after editing in notepad, the changes gets picked up.

I dont think the changes will be picked up without a checkout though.